# Memory Leaks in web application

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I've got a web application developed using Netbeans IDE. I added a Web Service from WSDL. The problem is that it becomes heavier and slower each time I deploy it. Sometimes it makes my IDE crash.

I don't know how to solve this problem. I read other questions on stackoverflow, but they just suggest to expand the permSpace or something similar. I would rather try to understand what's going wrong, and why my space isn't cleared as it should.

This is what I get in Tomcat's console:

```
INFO: WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed
13-nov-2013 16.24.02 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
GRAVE: The web application [/SOAPolls] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1@53c6a7fc]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@173ebc5c]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-nov-2013 16.24.02 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
GRAVE: The web application [/SOAPolls] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.glassfish.gmbal.generic.OperationTracer$1] (value [org.glassfish.gmbal.generic.OperationTracer$1@17c047f0]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-nov-2013 16.24.02 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
GRAVE: The web application [/SOAPolls] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@50b2e9be]) and a value of type [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class javax.xml.bind.annotation.W3CDomHandler=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@14a877c0, class com.sun.xml.ws.runtime.config.Tubelines=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@404de8d8, class java.util.ArrayList=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@3af1dde3, class com.sun.xml.ws.runtime.config.TubelineDefinition=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@5d1e8050, class com.sun.xml.ws.runtime.config.TubeFactoryList=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@7d7a33f2, class com.sun.xml.ws.runtime.config.MetroConfig=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@61e89539, class com.sun.xml.ws.runtime.config.TubeFactoryConfig=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@6c9d0366, class javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@384a553f}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-nov-2013 16.24.02 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
GRAVE: The web application [/SOAPolls] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.glassfish.gmbal.generic.OperationTracer$1] (value [org.glassfish.gmbal.generic.OperationTracer$1@17c047f0]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-nov-2013 16.24.03 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources
```

What can I do?

Plus: is there a way to manually clear the space I need, in order to make my application run for a bit more (a temporary solution since I've got an exam in the next days)?

**EDIT:** I tried to restart the server. But sometimes the IDE will not be able to undeploy the application when I try to stop Tomcat (and everything gets stuck).

Comment: Netbeans deploys on save, thus it keeps adding to the space. Just try to restart the server, if you have done this, ignore this

Comment: @lazyprogrammer I tried this. But sometimes the IDE will not be able to undeploy the application when I try to stop Tomcat.

Comment: The easiest option is to restart your server, instead of constantly redeploying.

Comment: @Kayaman I edited the question. As I said to lazyprogrammer, I tried to restart the server, but sometimes this doesn't help: all gets stuck in "undeploying" status, and I'm not even able to kill Tomcat process.

Comment: That's when it's too late. If you wanna play it safe, you use restart always instead of redeploying. If it still crashes, start using a better application server.

Comment: @Kayaman ok, I'll try as you suggest. I disabled the "Deploy on save" Netbeans option that could have caused troubles. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put all needed libraries files ( webservices*.jar, activation.jar) in the tomcat\lib directory, and remove them from your webapp WEB-INF\lib.

Comment: I'm not working on that project anymore, but could you be so kind to add additional details? Why should your advice work?

Comment: It works because I tested it. I have encountered the same problem and found this solution. I could hardly accept these kind of messages in the tomcat logs. Even if it has no negative effect on the production site, it give the impression that the software is seedy.

Comment: I am not a Tomcat developper but I think that the memory leaks come because different class loaders are involved in this story. Putting the library directly in tomcat fix it.